# How to sum selected rows in table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table

```
SUM | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
    | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
    | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
SUM | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
    | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
FOO | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
BAR | <input type="text"> | <input type="text"> |
```

I want to get sum of columns below "SUM row" when input value is changed. 
If there is other column ex FOO BAR it shouldn't be count to sum.

What is aproach here? Dummy idea: every column has reference where it value will be summed.

Fiddle for quick start:
http://jsfiddle.net/igos/vNxzu/

**EDIT**
It should sum up till next sum row right.

```
row 0 col 0  = row 1 col 0  + row 2 col 0
row 0 col 1  = row 1 col 1  + row 2 col 1
row 3 col 0  = row 4 col 0
row 3 col 1  = row 4 col 1
```

It should be dynamic, so when more rows come it will automatically add more rows.

Comment: it should sum up till next sum row right?

Comment: why not just add a class (e.g. `class="sumCell"`) and just use jQuery to select those cells and sum the value when a value changes?

Comment: @DavidHoerster because I don't know how to determine if I want to sum to first sumRow or the second.

Comment: so in your fiddle there 'll be 2 sums each one equal to (8 cells * 3 rows) right??

Comment: @ebramtharwat 2 sum rows each equal 2 rows below them.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ne5DM/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it works like a charm. Please post it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('tr.sumToUp input').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this), $row = $this.closest('tr'), $sum = $row.prevAll('.sumToMe').first(), $rows = $sum.nextUntil('.sumToMe', '.sumToUp'), index = $this.closest('td').index();

    var sum = 0;
    $rows.each(function(){
        var val = $(this).find('td').eq(index).find('input').val();
        sum += (+val);
    })
    $sum.find('td').eq(index).find('input').val(sum);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ne5DM/)